# stored procedure, msg 2812,

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've made a database and I'm trying to make some stored procedures for it,
I added a new query file to my database and i wrote the following code in it,

```
create procedure SEL_STUDENT
as
begin
select * from student
end
execute SEL_STUDENT
go
```

But anytime i try to execute the following line

```
execute SEL_STUDENT
```

it returns an error, saying,

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 53
>   Could not find stored procedure 'SEL_STUDENT'

Please help me fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: Be sure you are using required database and you have `SEL_STUDENT` procedure in that database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran your code using a table from the AdventureWorks2012 database.

```
create procedure SEL_STUDENT
as
begin
select * from [Person].[Person]
end
go

execute SEL_STUDENT
```

And it works fine.

Although I have moved `GO` above `execute SEL_STUDENT` that is not the issue here as @CoOl points out because you specifically say you execute the stored procedure after your block of code.

The only possible explanation would be that you are querying `execute SEL_STUDENT` on the wrong database.

Try the following code -

```
USE [DatabaseName] 
GO

execute SEL_STUDENT
```

Here, [DatabaseName] is the database where the stored procedure `SEL_STUDENT` table is stored.

Make sure your table is also stored in the same database or else you would have to modify `select * from student` to `select * from [DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[student]`

Additionally, you can use the Object Explorer to identify where your stored procedure has been saved. I am unable to post a snapshot of how to do this as my reputation is below 10.

EDIT : Now that my reputation is in two digits -

[image]

Kindly note that [dbo] is the default schema in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to execute the Stored Procedure which is not there yet.

Move `GO` above `execute SEL_STUDENT`

```
create procedure SEL_STUDENT
as
begin
select * from student
end
go

execute SEL_STUDENT
```